# Who or what was Songbird?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I've completed the game, and I'm wondering/hoping if I missed something important connected with this fascinating creature of the developers' imagination.

> We know that Songbird was **protector of Elizabeth** and her only **so called friend**.
>  It was **summoned by flute music**. Songbird was nearly unstoppable - killing him by drowning **in Rapture depths** shows that. His death also reveals that it had **violet blood**. Songbird's eye colour depends from its mood there was green - peaceful, yellow - alarmed and red - aggressive.

How was it created? Does it eat anything? Was it originally human?

Am I too curious and I should accept that this is only a game and some questions aren't going to be answered?

I've never played Bioshock 1 or 2 so I don't know anything about the Big Daddies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Songbird was built at the Fink Factory, you can see [the blueprints there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAAsn.jpg). Where they got the technology is the **interesting** part:

> The technology came from another dimension; It is never directly stated but it is quite possible that dimension is the one with the Rapture city from Bioshock 1 & 2. The same technology was used to build the Big Daddies.

This would imply that Songbird is a brainwashed human with machine augmentations.

[image: songbird diagram]

Comment: Wow! Do you have any screenshots :) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have screenshots and I should have explained myself better: Those "blueprints" are just drawings from the outside. Unfortunately, like Bioshock 1 & 2 Big Daddies, you never know what is inside.

Comment: Watch out for BioShock Infinite 2, where you will be playing as an [Alpha Series Songbird](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Subject_Delta).

Comment: Here's an even better version of the image: http://www.bioshockinfinite.com/images/media/screenshots/VetruvianSongbird.jpg

Comment: I edited in the version of the image that @mostlyautumn suggested.

Comment: [Here](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/A_Child_Needs_a_Protector) is the Voxophone record that implies that songbird is part human.

Answer (score 2):

The most passed around theory is that songbird is kyle fitzpatrick from bioshock 1 or, songbird was there atleast, as if you listen close at his death scene you hear the songbirds' squawk and cry's. Ign has a clip on youtube that you can hear it pretty well on.

Here is said clip, you have to listen carefully
over the talking of fitzpatrick and the piano, hope this helps :)

Comment: It's far more likely that Irrational just reused the same sound effect from their soundbank.

Comment: I can't hear it :(

Comment: Also, considering the early trailers had given Songbird a much deeper, growlier 'voice', I highly doubt there was any connection between the two sounds, however tantalising that might have been. Unless it was a quadruple bluff. Curse you, Levine!

Answer (score 1):

While Songbird is machine, I don't believe he is human in any aspect except the fact that he protects Elizabeth like the Big Daddies. While this is out there, on an unrelated note, A voxophone with Father Comstock in the Good Time Club says a line that caught my attention:

> ...Or, drown his flock in waters of the ocean.

This means, in my opinion, that

> Comstock knew about Rapture before Songbirds creation.

Comment: Hi, I added a couple of spoiler tags as there's some info regarding the end of the game in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you notice RIGHT at the very end at 1:25 the sound once again repeats itself. Also many many many times in Bioshock 2 are the exact same sounds.

My conclusion : This was supposed to be Dolphins communicating as ambient noise recycled to become the Songbird

Answer (score 0):

This Bioshock 2 trailer explains that Songbird was created to keep Elizabeth in -

http://gamerant.com/bioshock-infinite-trailer-songbird/

Answer (score -2):

When I was at the point where she says goodbye to the Songbird for the last time (I don't want to spoil it but if I say "Water, water everywhere and not a drop to drink" you'll know what bit I'm on about) I was actually starting to think the game was leading to Booker being the Songbird, just because we found out he was Elizabeth's father and the Songbird protected her the same way a father would.

Also, what the heck was the debt? I thought it was that we were going to have to choose to kill baby Elizabeth and then that was why Booker had to give Comstock the >cough cough< to wipe away the debt of killing a baby version of Elizabeth. If you choose to kill it or even if you didn't then you'd become the Songbird as punishment for handing over the baby to Comstock. I think that would have been a good way to go. Also I think that the A.D. on his hand stood for Anna Dewitt, who I think is the baby version of Elizabeth.

Comment: I gave up reading after the first line... I really suggest you to read up on how to be a more effective writer...

Comment: never mind a lozenge, I think you need a dictionary or a browser with spelling and grammar check.

Comment: I tried to edit this but I sincerely had nothing to work with

Comment: I cleaned it up, but I'm not really sure this is actually an answer. You seem to basically be saying "It isn't Booker, but wouldn't it have been cool if it was?"

Comment: A late response, but "The debt" was Booker's literal gambling debt. The line "Bring us the girl, wipe away the debt" is the bargain that was offered to Booker (by the Lutece's) before the start of the story. He essentially sold his child to Comstock in exchange for getting rid of his crushing gambling debts. The phrase haunts him throughout the game, but he doesn't actually remember its real context until the reveal at the very end. Instead, his mind invents a context for it, tricking himself into believing that it's related to this job he's on. Remember the quote from the start of the game.